# String is not being translated in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-localization

On an ASP.NET Core 2.0 view I have the following:

```
@inject IViewLocalizer localizer;

<div>
  @localizer["my message"]
</div>
```

This works and the string is translate.

Then on a class of the application I tried:

```
public class MyClass {

    public String Get(IStringLocalizer<MyClass> localizer) {

        var l = localizer["my message"];

    }
}
```

In this case the string is not translate and I get the following info:

```
Name [string]: "my message"
ResourceNotFound [bool]: true
SearchedLocation [string]: null
Value [string]:"my message"
```

What am I missing?

Comment: According to the object returned there was no resource to get the translation from. Are you sure you configured it correctly? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization#working-with-resource-files

Comment: I think I am. But if ViewLocalizer gets the string should not StringLocalizer get it to?

Comment: Where are you getting the StringLocalizer from?

Answer (score 0):

The localizer should be injected into the class as an explicit dependency via constructor injection.

```
public class MyClass {
    IStringLocalizer<MyClass> localizer;
    public MyClass(IStringLocalizer<MyClass> localizer) {
        this.localizer = localizer;
    }

    public string Get() {
         return localizer["my message"];
    }
}
```

[Globalization and localization in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization#working-with-resource-files)

Comment: That did not work ... Is it possible to inject IStringLocalizer instead of IStringLocalizer<MyClass>? I mean to get Shared Resources

Comment: @MiguelMoura wont hurt to try it and see.

Comment: @MiguelMoura Did you add `services.AddLocalization();` in `Startup.ConfigureServices` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization#implement-a-strategy-to-select-the-languageculture-for-each-request

Comment: @Nikosi Yes I do have that on my ConfigureServices

Comment: @MiguelMoura did u get this solved i am still having same issue in asp.net core 3.1